# Why $P(BB|BG \cup BB) = \frac{P(BB)}{P(BG \cup BB)}$?

Tags: probability, self-study

I have the following question:

*Determine the probability both children are boys if I have 2 children, the elder is a boy?*

Then the textbook says:

*Take BB, BG, GB, GG as the possible outcomes (first letter is elder kid) then:*
$$
P(BB|BG \cup BB) = \frac{P(BB)}{P(BG \cup BB)}
$$

However, how come we don't have:

$$
P(BB|BG \cup BB) = \frac{P(BB \cap (BG \cup BB))}{P(BG \cup BB)}
$$

which is basically what $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

I don't see how $BB \cap (BG \cup BB)$ would reduce to $BB$.

Comment: It's helpful if you provide the name and page of the book too.

Comment: @StatsStudent It's lecture notes actually.

Comment: Just make a  Venn diagram of $BB$ and $BG \cup BB$ and see what ends painted by both colours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You both are right.  But here's a hint to get the answer in your notes:  According to Probability Distributive Laws:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P[BB\cap(BG\cup BB)] & = & P[(BB\cap BG)\cup(BB\cap BB)]
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, to reduce, what do $P(BB\cap BG)$ and $P(BB\cap BB)$ reduce to?